# How to display a Geomap in different colors from external click using JS

Tags: javascript, geomap

I'm trying to use a geomap using 2 color schemes. the user will click a link on the page and then, using js, i will change the color of the map and redraw it.

i would change

```
options['colors'] = [0xbaecc7, 0x3bc75f]; // light to dark green
```

The problem is that every time i call the function to redraw it seems to reload the geomap. I have two functions.. the one below is for green and the otherone is for drawing the blue map.
At the start i draw the blue map using `drawMap` by calling `setOnLoadCallBack`

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
```

Any help or ideas would be appreaciated!

```
function drawGoalsMap() {
            var options = {};
            options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
            options['region'] = 'world';
            options['colors'] = [0xbaecc7, 0x3bc75f]; // light to dark green
            options['width'] = '900px'; 
            options['height'] = '400px';

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addRows(6);
            data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Messages');
            data.setValue(0, 0, 'Germany');
            data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
            data.setValue(1, 0, 'United States');
            data.setValue(1, 1, 300);
            data.setValue(2, 0, 'Brazil');
            data.setValue(2, 1, 400);
            data.setValue(3, 0, 'Canada');
            data.setValue(3, 1, 500);
            data.setValue(4, 0, 'France');
            data.setValue(4, 1, 600);
            data.setValue(5, 0, 'RU');
            data.setValue(5, 1, 700);

            var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
            var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
            geomap.draw(data, options);

            google.visualization.events.addListener(geomap, 'regionClick', 
                function(e) {
                                var countryCode = e['region'];
                                DrillDown(countryCode);
                            }
            );

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chance edit in my code I found the problem!!!

I was using the link `<a href="" onclick="drawGoalsMap()">Goals</a>`

I changed it to exclude the `href=""`

```
<a onclick="drawGoalsMap()">Goals</a>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the `<a>` as a link, another easy way is to do this: `<a href="#" onclick="drawGoalsMap(); return false">Goals</a>`